# Responsive YouTube embedded video set to specific dimensions without black borders

Tags: css, youtube, responsive

After extensive research, I feel that I have exhausted efforts in trying to not only embed a YouTube video set to specific dimensions, without black borders, but also have it be responsive.

I've managed to get rid of the black borders and keep the video set to specific dimensions, but in my case, the video is not responsive.

Is anyone able to please assist with the following?

Specific dimensions
No black borders
Response

Here is my code:

```css
    .videowrap {
    height:360px;
    width:640px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .videowrap iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    }
```

```html
<iframe width="640" height="360" class="videowrap" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com" frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
    picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

If by responsive you mean on different screen sizes. You can use @media for different screen sizes. For example:

```
    @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .videowrap {
    height:180px;
    width:320px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
// or any other css you want to put in here
    }
```

Comment: If the answer helped please verify the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've added the CSS snippet and that did not seem to do the trick. Any other thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell what do you mean by responsive exactly?